# ItextSharp Error : Document has no pages

Tags: asp.net, pdf, itext

I am using itextsharp to convert my asp.net page to pdf. on button click i am writing following code :

```
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    //GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
```

but i am getting error : "Document has no page" 
please help me to get rid of this error and generate the pdf.

Comment: can you create a template pdf file?

Comment: Got one solution on this link : http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t63572-convert-an-aspx-page-to-a-pdf-file-with-asp-net-c.html

However the Page Contents are converted in plain format in pdf. is there a way to keep original markup as it is in pdf (colors etc)?

Comment: check sw.ToString() is string.Empty or not.

Comment: @ketan *I Think this Question need a well understanding answer* - it first needs additional details which quite likely wont come forth as the OP has not been here for half a year.

Answer (score 0):

Two steps needed to be taken for this:

1) Check ITextSharp dll is latest version

and

2) Take link button instead of button and DON'T take hyperlink as it will give error with  hyperlink button.